# Why is HP Fortify showing "Dereferenced" issue in logger statements?

Tags: java, fortify

```
OurLogger.writeLog(LogType.INFO, "SubAccountId",
                "SomeAccNumber:" + Long.toString(userAccountNumber) + "::" + subAccIdKeySet,
                LogStatus.SUCCESS.toString());

if (null == subAccIdKeySet || thisKey.isEmpty())
            return Collections.emptyList();
```

Fortify is giving below analysis trace:

> Dereferenced: subAccIdKeySet
>
> Compared with null: subAccIdKeySet

I am not understanding how its dereferenced and what fix should I approach?

Comment: Most probably because a check `null == subAccIdKeySet` is comming after the use of `subAccIdKeySet`. I believe it's not taking into account that `"::" + subAccIdKeySet` would not be prone for a NPE.

Comment: I went through this: https://coderanch.com/t/367369/java/meant-dereferencing and found that **dereferencing (in java) = Action of accessing an object's features through a reference.**. You are right about the null comparison issue. For the dereferencing one, I tried in local by adding a null check in first dereference i.e. in the logger method call. It did not report again. But there are just too many of them!! Now thats a headache :-)